# rawQuery wild card `"_"` not working

Tags: android, sqlite, wildcard

I have been trying to use the character wild card `"_"` in sqlite where conditions and am close to "jumping off a high place" I have tried both rawQuery and query with a variety of hard and soft coded parameters. It seems to ignores the character wild card `"_"`and returns all rows or none at all.

The data held is in several columns representing a features of an oblect for example a column may represent the colours of an object

```
("red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indego,violet,black")
```

and a row's colour could be "01001000" meaning that it is orange and blue but not red, yellow etc. other columns contain single characters ie size contains s,m or l (mapping  small, medium, large ) the database holds several columns of each type, the idea to have as compact a database as possible.

My first intention was to code by passing the 'where' of my select as a string to the `rawQuery(myselect,null)` where the myselect was compiled in the code in response to several features selected by the user.
ie

the mywhere string is compiled to return :- 
colour1 like `"_1__10__"` and colour2 like `"___1_01__"` and size =`"l"` 
and passed to the rawQuery

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT _id , name FROM widgets WHERE " + mywhere , null);
```

The statement below works fine using Firefox's SQLite Manager

```
SELECT _id , name FROM widgets WHERE colour1 like "_1__10_" and colour2 like "__1_01___" and size ="m"
```

In order to investigate I have cut the query down to one column in the where clause

```
myselect ="SELECT _id ,name,FROM widgets where colour1 like  \"1_______\"";
cursor = db.rawQuery(myselect,null);
```

returns no rows

```
myselect ="SELECT _id ,name,FROM widgets where colour1 like  \"%1_______%\"";
cursor = db.rawQuery(myselect,null);
```

returns rows but not all have a 1 at the first char ( I expected this )

```
myselect ="SELECT _id ,name, FROM widgets where colour1 like ?";
String[] whereArguments = { "1_______" };
cursor = db.rawQuery(myselect,whereArguments);
```

returns no rows

```
myselect ="SELECT _id ,name, FROM widgets where colour1 like ?";
String[] whereArguments = { "%1_______%" };
cursor = db.rawQuery(myselect,whereArguments);
```

returns rows but not all have a 1 at the first char

But I dont get any rows from

```
myselect ="SELECT _id ,name, FROM widgets where colour1 like ?";
String[] whereArguments = { "10000000" };
cursor = db.rawQuery(myselect,whereArguments);
```

and there are rows containing "10000000"

Does any one have any solutions? I have tried searching but it seems that rawQuery and query have questionable functionality in Android.

Comment: I have found my problem ! I exported the data I had created in Firefox's SQLite Manager to create the SQLite database in Android not realising that each column was appended with a space at each end so where I thought the data contained "10000000" it actually held " 10000000 ".

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your main source of problems, but the string delimiter in SQLite is the single quote character  (') not the double quote one ("). See [this](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q14), for example.

Comment: dmon Thanks. I come from an Oracle background and am under the impression that either " or ' pairs are string delimiters in SQL whether it is in SQLite ?. Your example is for embedding a single-quote (') not delimiting the string. Anyway just in case you were correct I carried out the above tests using ' in the select statements with the same results. Java prohibits ' in the String[] whereArguments = { '1_______' }; but I understand from the documentation that rawQuery's selectionArgs values are bound as Strings.